# Firefox playing flash movie doesn't show up in Ubuntu 9.10 Sound Preferences

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-9.10, flash-player

I have just upgraded from Ubuntu 9.04 to 9.10.  The sound is working fine for:

1. On disk Movies(*.avi, *.flv)
2. Music(*.mp3)

I'm currently watching youtube or other flash movies on Firefox 3.5.7 which play fine but there is no sound at all.  Whenever I listen to music or watch a movie, the media software that I use will show up under the `Applications` tab of `Sound Preferences` which can be accessed through `System -> Preferences -> Sound`.

For instance, `Rhythmbox` shows up if I am listening to music.  When I watch youtube on Firefox or Chrome, nothing shows up under the `Applications` tab.  Does anyone know how to fix this issue?  I believe that once this issue is fixed, my flash videos through a web browser will have sound again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be a permission issue.  Just make sure root and your username(using `jdoe` as example) is associated with the following groups in `/etc/group`:

```
audio:x:29:jdoe,pulse
pulse:x:121:root,jdoe
pulse-access:x:122:root,jdoe
```

I guess you could also do the following from the `Users and Groups` GUI but I just can't find it on my OS(another issue to fix).